# How to find bottleneck on web server stack: Debian + Apache + FastCGI

Tags: linux, debian, performance

I'd like to ask advice how to find a bottleneck in the follow stack:

Debian (Debian GNU/Linux 6.0) + Apache + mod_fcgi/FastCGI + my+application

The web server is used for images only.

I need a check list to go over and figure out answer to the question:
"Is the server squeezed (means we need an additional) one or it's possible to optimize further?"

Thank you!

Comment: If you are serving static images, consider Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache - it should greatly improve performance for static files. If it is a PHP application you might get better performance with php-fpm instead of mod_fcgi.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're [fundamentally] serving static content, just time your raw disk I/O with something like bonnie++ (http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/), then figure out what your raw network throughput is.  Once you have those numbers, do some load testing with something like Tsung (http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) to see what sort of impact apache/mod_fcgi has.

That said, a webserver like Nginx (http://nginx.net/) might out perform Apache for your use case.  It has a smaller memory footprint (more can run concurrently), and serving static content's one of its stronger points.